# Ef core Odata Many-to-many

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework-core, odata

I'm developing Asp .Net Core 2.2 application with ODATA. I have test application to reproduce the problem:
I can't request **linked entities with link table via ODATA** request.

Request: /odata/Books?$expand=BookCategories

response error:

```
"Message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Property 'BookCategories' on type 'GameStorageView.Data.Book' is not a navigation property or complex property. Only navigation properties can be expanded.",
"ExceptionMessage": "Property 'BookCategories' on type 'GameStorageView.Data.Book' is not a navigation property or complex property. Only navigation properties can be expanded.",
"ExceptionType": "Microsoft.OData.ODataException",
```

model:

```
 public class Book
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
    }

    public class BookCategory
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public Book Book { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

Model creating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>()
                .HasKey(bc => new {bc.BookId, bc.CategoryId});
            modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>()
                .HasOne(bc => bc.Book)
                .WithMany(b => b.BookCategories)
                .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.BookId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>()
                .HasOne(bc => bc.Category)
                .WithMany(c => c.BookCategories)
                .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.CategoryId);
```

How to make it work? **How to request many-to-many entities via odata?**

UPD:

ODATA configured:
`.EntityType.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand(SelectExpandType.Allowed,10).Select().Page().Count();`

linq query works fine: 
`context.Book.Include(c=>c.BookCategories).ToArray()`

Comment: Could you please show code, which adds/creates Edm model?

Comment: I use code-first and fluent api, OnModelCreating method and model you can see above)

Comment: Could you please publish the test application to the GitHub? In this case, I'll be able to run local and try to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my solution is not best, but it works: we need to add field **Id** and **unique constraint** to it:

```
public class BookCategory
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public Book Book { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>().HasAlternateKey(bc => bc.Id);
```

and then if we want to load linked entities via odata, we also need to add link entity to odata routes. I use extension method so it looks like this:

```
public static void RegisterOdataRoute<TEntity>(this ODataConventionModelBuilder builder, string name = null, bool pluralize = true) where TEntity : class
        {
            name = name ?? $"{typeof(TEntity).Name}";

            var names = pluralize ? $"{name}s" : name;

            OdataRoutes.Add(name, $"~/odata/{names}");
            builder.EntitySet<TEntity>(names).EntityType.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand(SelectExpandType.Allowed,10).Select().Page().Count();
        }
    }
```

and

```
app.UseOData(builder =>
            {
                builder.RegisterOdataRoute<BookCategory>();
                    ...
```

If someone found a better solution, please let me know!